# Check if CoreData attribute is empty

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am hoping to find a way to check, if a CoreData attribute is empty. The attribute itself is of type binary data. If the attribute is empty then I could tell my class to download and save some data into this attribute.

According to CoreData Documentation, you should not keep fetching to see if objects exists. I am wondering if there is even a way to possibly do this? without breaking this 'law'?

This is my first attempt at using CoreData. I am adding it to my code afterwards, which is slightly more painful, but as a whole so far everything seems to be going okay. I just need to figure out a logical way of checking if attribute has values. If it doesn't then I need to download and save the new data, if it does then I just use what's in the attribute.

**Update :**

I just found this method in the CoreData framework that I have been reading though trying to catch a break on this. Not sure if it would help.. what do you guys think?

> [willAccessValueForKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/willAccessValueForKey:): Provides support for key-value observing access
>   notification.
>
> - (void)willAccessValueForKey:(NSString *)key Parameters key The name of one of the receiver's properties. Discussion See
>     didAccessValueForKey: for more details. You can invoke this method
>     with the key value of nil to ensure that a fault has been fired, as
>     illustrated by the following example.
>
> [aManagedObject willAccessValueForKey:nil];

Not sure really.. the things that I dont understand is **Provides support for key-value observing access notification.** ???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That notification is for when the value is going to be accessed.

If I understand you correctly, you are not wanting to see if an entity exists, but an attribute within the entity.  So, I assume you have it marked as an optional attribute.

Let's say you have a binary data attribute called rawData.  If you want to find all the @"MyEntity" objects in the database that do not have any data set for this attribute, you cn issue this fetch request.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rawData = nil"];
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:0];
```

Comment: okay cool.. thanks for that. Its just abit of a worry because I have read that issuing to many fetch requests is a naughty thing to do.. :P

Comment: You can always prevent someone from ever creating an object with an empty attribute by making it non-optional.  Or you can build objects that monitor the database changes and add/remove objects to a global list when the have the spacial nil/non-nil attribute value.